# how to do something repeatedly in a database action?

Tags: authentication, go

I am writing a user authentication system in `go`.First of all I prompt user to signup the form with email, username and password. Then I send a confirmation link to users email. The user must also select a title for his blog.Which is prompted after the confirmation link is clicked. How to ensure that the user don't move to the home page without a title.

My `ConfirmEmail` function is below:

```
func ConfirmEmail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil{
      log.Fatal("Unable to parse data")
    }
    token := r.Form.Get("token")
    db.ConnectDB()
    current_time := time.Now().Unix()
        user_id := 0
    var date_generated int64
    var date_expires  int64
    var date_used     int64
    row := db.Db.QueryRow("Select user_id, date_generated, date_expires, date_used from Token where token = ?", token)
    if err := row.Scan(&user_id, &date_generated, &date_expires, &date_used); err != nil{
       if err == sql.ErrNoRows{
        //todo: no such token provide a link to signup..
        fmt.Println("No such rows..")
       } else {
        log.Fatal("Something went wrong:", err)
       }
    }

   //reuse of the token...
    if (date_used != 0){
       http.Redirect(w,r, "/signup", http.StatusFound)
    }
    // use of expired token...
    if(date_expires < current_time){
        //todo: inform about the expired token and prompt for re confirmation..
        fmt.Println("Token expired..")

    } else{
        //todo: Check for blog title, if null prompt.
        var title string
        var username string
        if err := db.Db.QueryRow("select username, blogTitle from User where user_id = ?", user_id).Scan(&username, &title); err != nil{
            if err == sql.ErrNoRows{
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/signup", http.StatusFound)
            }
        }
        //want to do this until title is not provided..
        if len(title) == 0{
            err = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "chose-title.html", struct {
                Username string 
                Msg string
                }{
                Username: username,
                Msg: "",
                })
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Unable to render provided template:",err)
               }
            return 
        }
        _, err = db.Db.Exec("Update Token set date_used = ? where token=?",current_time, token)
        if err != nil {
          log.Fatal("Unable to update with given data")
         }

        _, err = db.Db.Exec("Update User set Verified = true where user_id=?",user_id)
        if err != nil {
          log.Fatal("Unable to update with given data")
         } else {
           http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
          }
    }
}
```

The main problematic part is:(contains snippet from previous block)

```
if len(title) == 0{
        err = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "chose-title.html", struct {
            Username string 
            Msg string
            }{
            Username: username,
            Msg: "",
            })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Unable to render provided template:",err)
           }
        return 
    }
    _, err = db.Db.Exec("Update Token set date_used = ? where token=?",current_time, token)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Unable to update with given data")
     }

    _, err = db.Db.Exec("Update User set Verified = true where user_id=?",user_id)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Unable to update with given data")
     } else {
       http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
      }
}
```

I can think of a `while` loop in this, but don't think that would be a feasible option. Is there any other workaround or workflow to check this.

Comment: You can also prompt the user after login.

Comment: If the ConfirmMail form is not valid, then execute the input template with values from the  form and an error message.  To put this another way, respond with the input page until the user gets it right.